# How do you count the number of children in a Scriban template?

Tags: sxa, scriban

Given a page or item, how do I count the number of children?

{{ i_page.children }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
{{- childrenCount = i_page.children | array.size -}}
{{ childrenCount }}
```

Comment: What is your reference for figuring that out? If I google "sriban array.size" I find nothing !

Comment: Mostly exploring the Scriban docs. https://github.com/lunet-io/scriban/blob/master/doc/language.md